# How to make ComboBox as a trigger to show a file by selected the folder using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

Anyone can give me idea, please...
I would like to bring files to GroupBox GUI as a CheckBox format.
Because the files inside of some folder, I create ComboBox to make user easy to choose which folder they need to see the files.
I do some stuff here, but I still struggle to show the file. Once I execute my script, all the files appear in the GroupBox without select the folder first.
My expectation, the files will show only user select the folder.

Please give me some idea, I am newbie with PowerShell,really appreciated with the help. Thank you.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.text                       = "Form"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false
$Form.FormBorderStyle            = "FixedDialog"
$Form.MaximizeBox                = $false
$Form.startposition              = "centerscreen"
$Form.WindowState                = 'Maximized'

$Panel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
$panel.Dock = "Fill"
$panel.ColumnCount = 1
$panel.RowCount = 1
$panel.CellBorderStyle = "single"
$panel.ColumnStyles.Add((new-object System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle([System.Windows.Forms.SizeType]::Percent, 100)))
$panel.RowStyles.Add((new-object System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle([System.Windows.Forms.SizeType]::Percent, 100)))

$Groupbox1                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Groupbox
$Groupbox1.text                  = "Group Box"
$Groupbox1.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(8,13)
$Groupbox1.Padding               = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Padding -ArgumentList (0,5,5,0)
$Groupbox1.Dock                  = "fill"


$Combo                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$Combo.width                  = 190
$Combo.height                 = 20
$Combo.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(35,80)
$Combo.Font                   = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,12'
$Combo.AutoSize               = $true
$FolderList = @(Get-ChildItem -Directory ".\").Name
foreach ($folder in $FolderList) {
    $Combo.Items.Add($folder)
}

$Checkboxes += New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Checkboxes = @()
$y = 200
$FileTarget = @(Get-ChildItem ".\*\*" -Filter *.que).Name 
foreach ($file in $FileTarget)
{    
    $Checkbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    $Checkbox.Text = $file
    $Checkbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,$y) 
    $Checkbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1000,20) 
    $y += 20
    $Groupbox1.Controls.Add($Checkbox) 
    $Checkboxes += $Checkbox
    $Checkbox.Visible = $false
}

$form.controls.add($Panel)
$panel.controls.AddRange(@($Groupbox1))
$Groupbox1.controls.AddRange(@($Combo))
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: You can add a $Combo.SelectedIndexChanged event to get the right files, but even then you'd need to redraw the form to add them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$Combo.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $Checkboxes += New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    $Checkboxes = @()
    $y = 200
    $FileTarget = Get-ChildItem -Path $Combo.Text -File
    Foreach ($file in $FileTarget) {    
        $Checkbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
        $Checkbox.Text = $file
        $Checkbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,$y) 
        $Checkbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1000,20) 
        $y += 20
        $Groupbox1.Controls.Add($Checkbox) 
        $Checkboxes += $Checkbox
        $Checkbox.Visible = $true
    }
    $Form.Refresh()
})
```

Comment: hi @Scepticalist, I tried that's one, but I found a problem. Once I  choose 1 item of comboBox, it show the file but if I choose other ComboBox item, the previous file still exist, my expectation, If I choose other comboBox item, the previous one should be dissapear. Could you please help me, Thank you